# Is the PDF sent over the network with Adobe Embed API?

Tags: adobe-embed-api

I would like to use the Adobe Embed API to display PDF in an enterprise internal application. But I'm wondering if the PDF itself is sent to the Adobe servers?
Since the documents are strictly confidential, that would forbid me to use this API.

Comment: If you are working with strictly confidential documents I suggest you get your Cyber Security team to work it out. Looking at this https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/pdf-embed.html, it's a link, it's not actually embedded. There is absolutely no security around this. Anyone can get the client id and look at your PDF

Answer (score 3):

Adobe PDF Embed API does not upload your PDF document to Adobe servers. There is a whitepaper here that details that:
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/cc/en/security/pdfs/AdobeDocumentServices_SecurityOverview.pdf

Here is an excerpt:

> API  Authentication PDF Embed API is a client-side JavaScript- and
> WASM-based library and does not make any calls to cloud-based
> services. There are only three purposes for which it makes network
> calls:
>
> 1. At the time of loading, it calls into a service that validates the
>    client.
> 2. If given an Adobe Analytics report suite ID by the PDF Embed API integrator, it logs event data for out-of-the-box  analytics  and  a
>    pre-configured  analytics  dashboard.
> 3. It logs anonymous usage data in Adobe Analytics.